# How to put client TimezoneOffset into initial request?

Tags: javascript, servlets, timezone

I want calculate the client time based on server time. So TimezoneOffset is needed in **initial** request.

Please notice **initial** request not normal request.

My current solution is not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = setTimeZoneInCookie;

    function setTimeZoneInCookie() {
        var _date = new Date();
        var _offset = _date.getTimezoneOffset();
        document.cookie = "TIMEZONE_COOKIE=" + _offset; //Cookie name with value
    }
</script>
```

Then read cookie in request

```
Cookie[] cks = request.getCookies();
```

Comment: What doesn't work currently?

Comment: the initial request has send out while window.onload exec. So, the initial request will not contain the cookie set after the request.

Comment: the initial request send out, server side render the jsp, then client will download css,js,html and after that onload will exec

Comment: Any way the solution is not work and the initial request never include the cookie i set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we should not calculate client time in server side.

The best solution:

1. get server time from ajax
2. format the server time using javascript function to local time(do it
   in Windows.onload)

it works either initial request or normal request.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question and your itself is giving answer to correct your question. Are you doing this to boot your reputation?